# What is wrong with angular component?

Tags: angularjs

What is wrong with angular component ?

[image]

Comment: components aren't functions?  remove the `function()` part of the declaration.

Comment: Almost 900 rep and still posting images instead of code...

Comment: even your linter is telling you your syntax is invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

second argument should be an object literal. see example https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

```
angular.module('heroApp').component('heroDetail', {
  templateUrl: 'heroDetail.html',
  controller: HeroDetailController,
  bindings: {
    hero: '='
  }
});
```

Comment: any idea why you can't define the object literal externally? like `.component('foo', foo); var foo = {}`

Comment: var foo = {} should go first before .component('foo', foo)